# Is it possible to develop an IOS application without a Mac?

Tags: ios, app

I'm a postgraduated student and I had the idea to build an app for elementary school kids.

My question after many days of searching is whether anyone here have ever tried and what was their experience of developing an IOS app on other platforms than Xcode such as Phonegap, Monotouch, flex or others?

Comment: See [Alternatives For iOS Development Under Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4533847/643383).

Comment: You still need a Mac to use MonoTouch. Short bottom line answer is, you need a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use phonegap you need a mac at least to generate the keys to build the app. SO you might not need one every day but you will need access from time to time.

Comment: I m trying to set up phonegap but i am still confusing about the way things done.. i m gonna try 5-6 tools such us monotouch , marmelade and see how can i develop the game app for children..and i would appreciate so much if anyone had any experience with the above platforms and can share their reviews....(Sorry for the "bad" english i m trying to do my best!!)

Comment: No problem. For phonegap you can do most of your development in HTML and Javascript and you can use their build tool to do the actual building of the app. But you need a mac do some setup and you may need one to install the software on the device.